# Extending objects in Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, class, bind, this, instance

Can a function using $this variable be extended to another object? Or is the $this variable bound to the original object in which it was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While defining a class in PHP, `$this` is a variable to reference the individual instance of a class (a.k.a. the object) so, when inheriting from the first class, the child class would interpret `$this` as an instance of the child class.

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

(Pay attention to the 'object context' part)